# Join two tables and OUTPUT RESULT WITH COMMA

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

i have 2 tables 1st table contain 3 columns id, name and dept_id and 2nd table have 2 columns dept and id i want output in 2 columns 1st is "DEPT_NAME" and 2nd column "NAME" and all name show in 1 row which are related to particular department and name separated by comma like if dept_name is HR then name should be like rick, marsh

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select Dept, STUFF((SELECT ','+ Name 
                   FROM Table1 T1 
                   WHERE T1.Dept_Id=T2.ID for xml path('')),1,1,'')Name
FROM Table2 T2
```

Comment: thanx Rajesh its working for me but i am always confuse about that how xml data working in sql server and how to use xqueries please suggest me some good stuff about it